# Angular test: how to mock a service response?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I recently created a web application with Angular. I would like to test a **component that uses a service**. This service has a method that returns a rather complex Observable object.
This is the essential part of a method (invoked in turn by `ngOnInit`) in my component that uses the service to obtain the response:

```
myMethod(param1, param2) {

    this.myRealService.getValues(param1, param2).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log("My response: ", response.body)
      }
    ); 
}
```

Now I'll show you what I do in the component's `.spec.ts file`. I imported `import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';`:

```
const mockService = {

   myService: {
     someNumber1: 1,
     someNumber2: 2
   },


    getValues: function (param1, param2) {
     
      return of(this.myService);
      
    }

}
```

Obviously everything is inside a `describe` block (I do not report the entire code because it is full of dependencies etc ... that do not concern the problem). The important thing is that, in my file, I do:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent],
      imports: [],
      providers: [{provide: MyRealService, useValue: mockService}],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

By explicitly stating that I am replacing the use of the service with my mock. I would like the component method `myMethod` to be tested with the response object **equal to my mock object in the test**. Unfortunately this does not happen. Karma console prints this:

[image]

My response: `undefined`. Surely I'm wrong something but the problem seems easy to me. How do I correctly mock the data and pass it through without errors so that in the console I see my mocked data?

Comment: 1. In the component you try to console log response.body. That structure is not followed in the service mock.


2. If your subscription starts in ngOnInit, you will probably need to call detectChanges after component creation

Comment: I call detectChanges after component creation! But it's the component creation process itself that stumbles upon the call. Your answer is not very helpful

Comment: There doesn’t seem to be anything wrong with your code. Can you maybe share the constructor for your component, and also maybe the complete test file?

Answer (score -1):

check out this working Stackblitz I made as an example using cats.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-with-jasmine-and-cats?file=app/app.component.spec.ts